# Backbone.js and its API confusion

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, api, rest, backbone.js

I've recently started using `Backbone.js`. I like the architecture, in terms of features it's almost exactly what I need...

... However I found the following caveats:

- For `Collection`s `get` means something different than for `Model`s. There is no `set`. Attributes should be accessed in a regular way. I find it rather inconsistent. It's easy to confuse models and collections sometimes. Is there anything that can be done to overcome this?
- Assigning initial values inside `Model.extend` doesn't always work. For example assigning `url` will *not* override the default behaviour. This can only be achieved through a call to `set()` method. Again very error prone.
- I still don't know whether it's required to use `get`/`set` inside `initialize()` call.
- I don't understand why I can't just call `_.bindAll(this)` inside `initialize()` and I have to list specific function names to be bound like this: `_.bindAll(this, firstFunc, secondFunc, ...)`. This is not very DRY.

I would like to know: what are the best practices regarding the mentioned situations? What do you do to make the framework more consistent - any monkey patching? Am I doing anything wrong / against the convention?

I'd be grateful for any good real world examples. I did find this: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html and http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/01/backbone-js-part-1/ and those don't address any of the mentioned problems. In fact they just present the simplest ideas and absolutely no border cases, so anything more complicated could be useful.

**EDIT:**

Ok, and there is one more fundamental think I don't understand:

- Am I ever allowed to place additional attributes on extension like this: `var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ myattribute: myvalue })` ?

  - If so, then why don't subsequent calls to `new SomeModel().get("myattribute")` work ?
- What exactly is `this` inside `initialize()` ? Is it model class or model instance ?

**EDIT(2):**

Well, I found this: http://maccman.github.com/spine/. It looks like Backbone.js 2.0, shares a similar name too :). Haven't tested it yet, which might be a bit of a show stopper, as the library is *very* recent. However from the docs side of things it looks very promissing. It gets rid of most of the problems that I found, it simplifies the API, it even gets rid of the dependency on `underscore.js` which for a library is a good thing. I'll post my further findings here.

Comment: Good question, I too found Backbone a little strange. You should add your findings as answer to you own question.

Comment: @brianpeiris I will as soon as I establish that it is indeed usable. So far, so good. Spine really seems to be well thought through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I think I can say it quite confidently now: Backbone is dead, long live Spine.

Spine isn't exactly a fork of Backbone. It is however very similar and clearly inspired by some of the design decisions. It could be said that the author tried to retain as much as it was possible the original backbone API, getting rid of everything unnecessary or illogical. I find it also easier to extend. The list of changes includes among other things:

- Getting rid of the dreaded `Collection`s. "class methods" are used instead,
- Getting most out of js prototypical nature (i.e. no `get`/`set` is needed). Attributes are accessed directly. An explicit call to `save()` is required in order to trigger an event.
- `Views` and `Controllers` are now merged into new type of `Controllers` together whose purpose is to respond to DOM events and bind to model events.
- The name :)

I find those design decisions coherent and sensible.

Comment: I'm leaning more towards Spine as well. I have been using Backbone and the get('property') thing is a pain not only in code but as well as in templates. That is my only real beef with BackBone. 

I wish Spine had a View class. If you look at the element design pattern, it is exactly what View w/ Collection is in Backbone.

Comment: @mgutz Well it might a design pattern, however I've always found Collections redundant. And it's especially painful as they are virtually required (the way URL's are built by default). You can have Collections in Spine as well and it's less writing than not having Collections in Backbone.

Comment: @julkiewicz backbone is dead? your answer is more than a year old... is it still accurate?

Comment: @KinjalDixit I was wondering the same.  This seems like a well written article by someone who has implented both in real world projects: http://hjortureh.tumblr.com/post/22117245794/spinejs-vs-backbonejs . At the end he says: "As a conclusion I recommend when the key thing is simplicity or CoffeeScript integration choose Spine. In most other cases I recommend using Backbone with Underscore as the tool for the job."

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no 'set' for Collections is because Collections are not arrays, they are sets, which are potentially ordered.  The only supported way to place an element at a particular position is to add it to the collection and then sort the collection.

Comment: That's not what I meant. For `Models` `get()` means return a value of an attribute. Collections can have, and do have attributes as well - like say `.url`. However `get()` is reserved for accessing items. I wouldn't personally name identically two totally different functions - that's my point.

Comment: I understood that.  But you also said "there is no set."

Comment: Again, `set()` for `Model`s means set an attribute. However for a collection I'm supposed to set attributes directly. This is even more confusing as it is possible to mistakenly do the same to a model and by that fail to fire the appropriate triggers.

Comment: By this logic, you could never name any method "set," because it would confuse you too much about how to set values on other, unrelated classes.